# Understanding issue with "Routing and controllers" + Guideline for own Skeleton Application using Zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

Since Zend 1.xx and in new Zend 2.2.4 yesterday I found that Zend had removed Command Line interface and instead in their tutorials they had referred to a skeleton Application.

I had investigated and found that Zend had now focused on their documentation quite a good way like never before.

In their initial tutorials I was having some questions in section "Routing and controllers" where I am having difficulty on understanding the configuration scopes in "module.config.php" file located in module/Album/config/module.config.php (as per Zend's official User Guide)

Based on my shared above details I need two items of help from you.

1. A clear clarification on the configuration used and available in "module.config.php" as detailed as possible. Any external tutorial can be helpful a lot.
2. Any additional tutorial where I can see and understand creating my own Skeleton Application using Zend framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as your first question is concerned, please check out [my Blog about Understanding ZF2 Configuration](http://samminds.com/2013/04/understanding-zf2-configuration/).

As far as your second question is concerned, I'd question your reasoning. The sense of the ZendSkelettonApplication is to be the starting point for all your applications. Understanding what happens under the hood inside the Skeleton you pretty much have two options:

1. You use a Debugger like xDebug and basically follow the Applications workflow starting `public/index.php` and you understand that
2. You take the [Zend Framework Fundamentals Course](http://www.zend.com/en/services/training/course-catalog/zend-framework-2) - the internals of ZF2 will be described in that.